# Sitecore Experience editor is not resolving sc_site and only showing a single site for all items

Tags: experience-editor, multisite

I am facing `sc_site` resolve issue in Sitecore 9.2 experience editor and preview mode in multisite setup.

I have done all the possible setup in configs-

```
<setting name="Preview.ResolveSite" value="true" />
<setting name="Rendering.SiteResolving" value="true" />
<setting name="Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentSite" value="true" />
<setting name="Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentLanguage" value="true" />
```

Default site value is set to website-

```
Preview.DefaultSite ="website"
```

Sites name are correct in the Site config file. Please check a sample site configuration-

```
<site name="Sitename" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" dictionaryDomain="name" startItem="home"    database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" language="en"      htmlCacheSize="50MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" rootPath="/sitecore/content/sitename/itemName1/" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" scheme="https" />
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: When I am opening any page item in preview mode or experience editor, it is not resolving the site name in sc_site querystring. So unable to see proper layout in those views.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, after some internal discussion we found that he start path value is set "/home" in the config but in CMS it is "/Home". Now I changed the value to "Home" in the config file and its starts working fine now.
But I am not able to understand the root cause of this. Because same case issue is there in UAT and it's working fine there.

Can anyone please help me to find out the root cause?